# How to post data as csv file to rest endpoint in spring boot using WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, rest, csv

I'm trying to migrate data from an in house database to a software. The software has a REST api for this purpose, that expects a csv file.

A working curl call for this API endpoint looks like this:

```
curl -isk POST -H "customHeaderName:customHeaderValue" -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -F "data=@accounts.csv" <apiBaseUrl>/gate/account/import/group-accounts
```

My plan is to post the data directly to the REST endpoint with a spring boot application, without crating a physical csv file first.

My implementation looks like this, with "csvString" being a csv formatted String (e.g.: "*acc_id,acc_name,acc_desc\r\n1,john.doe,this is john\r\n2,peter.parker,this is peter*"):

```
(I removed this code and added the current version below.)
```

When I call `postAccountsAndGroups(csvString);` I get a 415 response indicating that my request body is not a proper `.csv` file.

**EDIT:**

It seems like the API endpoint requires a multipart form. Therefore I came up with something like this:

```
import static org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString;

import my.package.common.configuration.WebClientConfig;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.MultipartBodyBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyApiImpl implements MyApi {

  private final WebClient client;

  private final String apiBaseUrl;

  public MyApiImpl(
      @Qualifier(WebClientConfig.MY_API_CLIENT_CONFIG) WebClient client,
      @Value("${external.api.myapi.baseUrl}") String apiBaseUrl) {
    this.client = client;
    this.apiBaseUrl = apiBaseUrl;
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<HttpStatus> postAccountsAndGroups(String csvString) {
  
    MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    Resource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(csvString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    builder.part("data", byteArrayResource);
    
    
    return client.post()
        .uri(createAccountsUri())
        .header("customHeaderName", "customHeaderValue")
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
        .exchangeToMono(response -> {
          if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return response.bodyToMono(HttpStatus.class).thenReturn(response.statusCode());
          } else {
            throw new ServiceException("Error uploading file");
          }
        });
  }

  private URI createAccountsUri() {
    return fromUriString(apiBaseUrl).path("/gate/account/import/group-accounts").build().toUri();
  }
}
```

Now I get 400 Bad Request as response though.

Answer (score 0):

I stil havend found a way to implement my prefered solution. However I came up with this workaround, that relies on persisting the csv file:

In my case I chose "/tmp/account.csv" as file path since my application runs in a docker container with linux os. On a Windows machine you could use something like "C:/myapp/account.csv". The file path is injected vie the application.properties file using the custom value "migration.files.accounts" so it can be configured later.

```
import static org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString;

import my.package.common.configuration.WebClientConfig;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.MultipartBodyBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class PrimedexApiImpl implements PrimedexApi {

  private final WebClient client;

  private final String apiBaseUrl;

  private final FileSystemResource accountsFile;

  private final String accountsFilePath;

  public PrimedexApiImpl(
      @Qualifier(WebClientConfig.MY_API_CLIENT_CONFIG) WebClient client,
      @Value("${external.api.api.baseUrl}") String apiBaseUrl,
      @Value("${migration.files.accounts}") String accountsFilePath) {
    this.client = client;
    this.apiBaseUrl = apiBaseUrl;
    this.accountsFilePath = accountsFilePath;
    this.accountsFile = new FileSystemResource(accountsFilePath);
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<HttpStatus> postAccountsAndGroups(String csvString) {

    File csvOutputFile = new File(accountsFilePath);
    if (csvOutputFile.delete()) {
      log.info("An old version of '{}' was deleted.", accountsFilePath);
    }
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(csvOutputFile)) {
      pw.print(csvString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    builder.part("data", accountsFile);

    return client.post()
        .uri(createAccountsUri())
        .header("customHeaderName", "customHeaderValue")
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
        .exchangeToMono(response -> {
          if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return response.releaseBody().thenReturn(response.statusCode());
          } else {
            throw new ServiceException("Error uploading file");
          }
        });
  }

  private URI createAccountsUri() {
    return fromUriString(apiBaseUrl).path("/gate/account/import/group-accounts").build().toUri();
  }

}
```

I used spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.6.3 for this project.